# Requested URL is changing

Tags: iis, url

I have a website, at localhost:82
when I type this into IE, it comes up with a 404 error and the requested URL is localhost:80/wwwroot, which is not at all what I requested.

There is no URL rewrite set up.  I have tried to set up a tracing rule to see what is happening, however, the instructions at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/ say to look for "Fail Request Tracing" link, but it doesn't exist in my IIS 7.0 even under administrator.

Not sure where to look or why this is changing my requested URL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also tried moving the directory into the inetpub/wwwroot directory and setting the app up under the default website, but again it changed my URL from localhost:80/mywebsite/ to localhost/wwwroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) and check the HTTP response.

Comment: I ran fiddler, but it didn't pick up anything as it's running on my local machine.

Comment: Try connecting through the machine name; that should go through Fiddler.

Comment: Hi, I've managed to reinstall the web app from scratch, this has fixed my problem.  I will use your advice if I get the problem again.

thank you